# Spring @Transactional conditional propagation property

Tags: java, spring, transactions, transactional, propagation

Due to embedded Derby combatibility problems with multiple transations, I need to change the property propagation of @Transactional based on the profile that application started.

Example:
When application starts with the profile for running automatic tests, the @Transactional is configured with default propagation (Propagation.REQUIRED). When other profile is loaded, the propagation should set to Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.

How could I achieve this in Java Config? In xml config I have already did this in the past through aop:pointcut/aop:advisor and tx:advice, but I can't find a way to this in Java Config.

Comment: The `@Transactional` annotation has some settings/properties you can set when you use it. That's the way to go. Or are you trying to do it in a "global fashion"?

Comment: Yes I know, but how I could set that properties based on profile in Java Config?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible (ugly) solution. Using the @ImportResource annotation, I could import an xml file to my root java config file and in that file do the configuration that I want through AOP.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-dataaccess-aop-config.xml")
@Import(...)
public class RootConfig {}
```